# Draw Enum values assigned to Sprite

Tags: java, enums, libgdx

I'm making a game using LibGDX and I got 2 classes and one enum. My enum looks like this:

```
public enum Item {

    PEN, GLASS, AND, SO, ON;

    private static Item current = PEN;
    public static Item getNext() {
        current = values()[current.ordinal()];
        return current;
    }
```

In my first class is pieces of my game map where some of them are initialized with a value from the enum with this constructor:

```
public class MapPiece {

    private Sprite sprite;
    private Item item;

    public MapPiece (Sprite sprite, Item item) {
        this.sprite = sprite;
        this.item = item;
    }
```

This class also has a draw function that looks like this:

```
public void draw(Batch batch, float x, float y) {
    sprite.setPosition(x, y);
    sprite.draw(batch);
}
```

¨

In the last class I initialize my map pieces and put them in a 2D array like this:

```
atlas = new TextureAtlas("atlas.pack");
mapPieces[0][0] = new MapPiece(atlas.createSprite("piece"), Item.getNext();
mapPieces[0][1] = new MapPiece(atlas.createSprite("piec2"), Item.getNext();
```

...and so on until I added all my pieces

The itemSprites are created like this:

```
for ( Item i : Item.values()) {
    Sprite itemSprite = atlas.createSprite(i.toString());
```

The map pieces are being drawed on a sprite batch like this:

```
int mapPieceSize = 100;
for (int i = 0; i < mapPiece.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < mapPiece[0].length; j++) {
                    mapPiece[j][i].draw(spriteBatch, i * mapPieceSize, j * mapPieceSize);
                }
            }
```

Now to my problem. The textures for the items are the same size as the map pieces but are all transparent except in the middle where the item is. I made it like this to make it easier to position.

What I want to do is to draw a sprite of the items on top of the mapPiece that holds the enum value of the item. So for example, if `mapPiece[0][5]` holds the enum value `PEN` I would like to have a texture taken from my `atlas` called `PEN` and then draw on the same position as `mapPiece[0][5]`. I hope it´s not all too confusing.

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is...you described how you did anything, but not what went wrong. By the way, your Item enum's `getNext` method's `current = values()[current.ordinal()];` line doesn't do anything. Maybe it should be `current = values()[(current.ordinal()+1)%values().length];`

Comment: @Tenfour04 It's not really anything that have "gone wrong" is more that I have no idea on how to solve my problem (which I hope is clear) and all my attempts have failed.

Comment: Wait, I see where it's confusing. What is the `tiles` array? How is it different from the `mapPieces` array? Are they both the same size in both dimensions? Is the tiles array the background, and mapPieces the foreground elements? Because it seems weird that your for loop is comparing to `mapPiece.length` but pulling from the `tiles` array.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Ops, sorry it was just a mistake on my part to adapt the code for the question. I'll correct it. *Edit Updated so the code is correct now

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure I understand the problem yet, because I'm not sure where it's more difficult than what you've already done, but I suppose one way you could do it is like this.

Add a texture region field to the enum (not static).

```
public enum Item {

    PEN, GLASS, AND, SO, ON;

    private static Item current = PEN;
    public static Item getNext() {
        current = values()[(current.ordinal()+1)%values().length];
        return current;
    }

    public TextureRegion region;
}
```

Then fill in your texture regions to the enum instances right after loading the atlas.

```
Item.PEN.region = atlas.findRegion("PEN");
Item.GLASS.region = atlas.findRegion("GLASS");
...
```

And then when looping through your map pieces, draw the background tile, and the item tile:

```
int mapPieceSize = 100;
for (int i = 0; i < mapPiece.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < mapPiece[0].length; j++) {

        //You had a typo on this line
        mapPiece[j][i].sprite.draw(spriteBatch, i * mapPieceSize, j * mapPieceSize);


        //draw the texture region directly without using a sprite instance
        spriteBatch.draw(mapPiece[j][i].item.region, i * mapPieceSize, j * mapPieceSize);

    }
}
```

Also, you mentioned having a bunch of invisible padding around your items. That could waste performance by drawing a lot of invisible pixels. If you want to go in and tweak their positions, you can store an offset in the Item instance, or for each MapPiece instance and add that to the x and y locations when drawing the item.